# Confusing statement about package and import keyword in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

**"The first statement, other than comments, in a Java source file, must be the package declaration.
Following the optional package declaration, you can have import statements, which allow you to specify classes from other packages that can be referenced without qualifying them with their package."**

In MainActivity.java file I removed the package statement at the top of the file and it says that a required package is missing.  yet, according to the above statement it is optional. Can anyone explain?

Also, what is the difference between using the `package` and `import` keywords.  Is a package a collection of class files that have a .java extension? is import only used for just single class files.

The com.example.hello_world folder contains only the MainActivity.java file and no other files. So why do I have to use the `package` keyword instead of the `import` keyword?

thanks.

Comment: package is similar to a namespace in other languages. The package information is also important for the accessrights from different classes.. and so on. A good overview here [Link](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PackagesAccess1.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an Eclipse feature.

Your Java classes can be in any `package` regardless of where the corresponding `.java` file lives.

For example, you could have

```
package com.random;

public class DoesntMatter {}
```

and have this `.java` file live in `/usr/wtv/DoesntMatter.java`

In Eclipse, however, because of how it manages your project, a `.java` file that will be compiled must live in a folder hierarchy (inside a source folder) that matches the `package` declaration. If it isn't, Eclipse complains.

The `import` statement simply makes it possible for you to use the simple names of types. Instead of having to write

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("wtv");
```

you can write

```
import java.io.File;

...

File file = new File("Wtv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Package is the folder the file is in. It is optional only for cases where the file is not in a package.

Import is the file a statement is referencing from a different package.

If you only use `java.lang`, `java.lang.Object`, or files of the same package, **then you do not need to import** as long as they are unambiguous.

Comment: so if you use multiple .java files from the same package, instead of importing each one you can use the `package` statement? I tried this and it gave the following error: `syntax error on token "package, import expected."`

Comment: No, package is not the same thing as an import. Import is usage of a file in a different package in your code, package is where a file is placed.

Comment: so suppose i have two java files mainactivity.java and bundle.java and assume that i am editing the mainactivity.java file. if i want to use the bundle class in this file, I don't have to import it since bundle.java is located in the same folder where mainactivity is located? thanks.

Comment: Correct. You can also use the term package to describe where a file is located, and import to indicate which files you are using in your code.

Comment: no no i meant if mainactivity.java and bundle.java are located in the same folder do I have to still use the import command to use the bundle class file even though the package statement points to the current folder where mainactivity.java and bundle.java are both located? thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need to.